# Apache decoding semicolon - mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

Apache, receiving a request with an encoded semicolon (%3B) is decoding it before passing the request to a proxy (backend of Spring Tomcat).

Relevant apache Virtual host lines are:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

So for example when a request for URL like

```
http://testsite.com/page/%27+many+times%3B+the+valiant/author
```

Would be proxy forwarded as

```
http://testsite.com/page/%27+many+times/author
```

Is there something I can do to prevent apache from decoding that URL before forwarding it to proxy?

Perhaps [relevant issue noted on apache.org/bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50061)

Comment: Try you with `nocanon` directive?

Comment: @FedericoSierra Sorry.  Apache noob here.  What's the syntax for that directive?

Comment: Eg: `ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/ nocanon`

Comment: @FedericoSierra Can I buy you a beer?  Worked.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mod_proxy` canonicalise URLs passed to the backend. If you want suppress this behavior use `nocanon` keyword and this passes the URL path *"raw"* to the backend.

Eg:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/ nocanon
```